# MIPS can't multiply properly

Tags: mips

In MIPS, how can I translate this expression to MIPS?

`y = 2x+3z` (x,y,z are variables)

I use multi `$t0,$s0, 2 # $s0 stores x and $s1 stores y`. to show `2x`. Is that correct?

Comment: There is no `multi` instruction in the MIPS instruction set.  As @Turab says, multiplication by constant can often be done via simpler operations.  However, if you do want to multiply by a constant, just load the constant into a register, then use the regular `mul` or `mult` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that:
x is in $s0
z is in $s1
y will be in $s2

```
add $t0, $s1, $s1    # z*2 in $t0
add $t0, $t0, $s1    # z*3 in $t0
add $s2, $s2, $t0    # x*2+z*3 in $s2
```

We don't actually multiply (it's slower than simple addition) and as you can see we destroy temporary register $t0 but don't touch $s0/$s1

Answer (score 1):

MIPS instruction set doesn't provide a mult instruction with immediate value.

if we had:

$s0 = x, $s1 = y, $s2 = z

then the following generally works:

```
.text
 
main:
li $s0, 3           # x = 3
li $s1, 0           # y = 0
li $s2, 4           # z = 4

li $t0, 2           # first multiplier = 2
li $t2, 3           # second multiplier = 3

mult    $t0, $s0            # x * 2
mflo    $t0             # copy result to t0
add $s1, $s1, $t0               # add result to y

mult    $t2, $s2            # z * 3
mflo    $t2             # copy result to t2
add $s1, $s1, $t2               # add result to y

# print the equation result as integer
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s1
syscall
```